# Print SQL execution plan with python's module psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, sql-execution-plan, explain

Is there any way I can print the information from a SQL execution plan to see it in my Terminal when using python and the `psycopg2` module?

I tried the following, but nothing is shown in the Terminal:

```
cur.execute(cur.mogrify('explain analyze ' + sql_query, vals)
```

and using the `print` returns `None`:

```
print(cur.execute(cur.mogrify('explain analyze ' + sql_query, vals))
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862570/how-to-get-execution-plan-for-a-running-query-in-postgresql), I also tried the following, but did not work either:

```
cur.execute("LOAD 'auto_explain';")
cur.execute("SET auto_explain.log_min_duration = {min_ms};".format(min_ms=0))
cur.execute(sql_query, vals)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just after posting the question I figured out the answer. Quite basic actually. I just had to fetch it, like with any other `SELECT` command.

In case anybody else has the same question:

```
cur.execute(cur.mogrify('explain analyze ' + sql_query, vals))
analyze_fetched = cur.fetchall()
print(analyze_fetched)
```